# Remove first 2 from Array

Tags: php

I have this simple array and I'd like to know how I can stop the **first 2** segments from showing.

```
if(preg_match_all('/<td[^>]*class="sourceNameCell">(.*?)<\/td>/si', $printable, $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER));{
foreach($matches as $match) {

$data = "$match[1]";

    $array = array();
    preg_match( '/src="([^"]*)"/i', $data, $array ) ;
    print_r("$array[1]") ;
}
```

Any help would be great, Thanks!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=php+remove+from+array

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Stop from showing or removing?

for removing:

```
$array = array();
preg_match( '/src="([^"]*)"/i', $data, $array ) ;

// The following lines will remove values from the first two indexes.
unset($array[0]);
unset($array[1]);
// This line will re-set the indexes (the above just nullifies the values...) and make a     new array without the original first two slots.
$array = array_values($array);
// The following line will show the new content of the array
var_dump($array);
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Didn't seem to work, I think because I didn't clarify my code enough, I've made an edit for you.

Answer (score 137):

Use [`array_slice`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-slice.php):

```
$output = array_slice($input, 2);
```

Answer (score 7):

Use `array_slice($array, 2, count($array))` or make your regexp skip the first two if possible.

You could also invoke array_shift() twice on the array. This might be more optimal since it shouldn't need to make a copy of the array.

Comment: `count($array)` is unnecessary because it is the default.

Answer (score 2):

You could use [`array_splice`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-splice.php) to remove elements from array.

> array_splice — Remove a portion of the array and replace it with something else

Elements are removed from original array and returned

```
$input = array("red", "green", "blue", "yellow", "black");
$part = array_splice($input, 1, 2);
var_dump($input);
var_dump($part);
```

[See PHP fiddle](https://ideone.com/StFFta)

Comment: actually, the answer to the question would be `array_splice($input, 0, 2);`