# Skipping first two elements on string PHP

Tags: php, explode

I have an array response like this:

```
First#Second#Third#...#...# and etc.
```

I'd like to skip only first two elements and then get output as:

```
Third#...#...# and etc.
```

How can I make it? Already tried explode().

Comment: you can foreach and do a simple if key is not equal to 0 or 1  do.

Comment: Use [explode](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) and then [remove the first 2 array elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6723247/remove-first-2-from-array)?

Comment: "I have an array"  ==  "I have a string"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just an example how `explode()` can be used without having to chop, remove and glue back together.

Use the third parameter of `explode()` to limit it to 3 parts, so that everything from the there on is one piece and just pick this last part(I use `[2]` in this example)...

```
$input = 'First#Second#Third#...#...# and etc.';
$output = explode("#", $input, 3)[2];
echo $output;
```

gives...

```
Third#...#...# and etc.
```

Comment: That's a nice one-liner, but it will still be more expensive.

Comment: @RoAchterberg, the comparative difference is probably minor (unless you have anything to back it up).  Anyway it was more a case of how to make the best use of the API and how you can reduce the impact of the code (i.e. only having to do 1 part of the process rather than as you had assumed to having to do 3 separate parts).

Comment: What I have to 'back it up' is that explode() will have to do some internal string contorting that can be avoided by using something more lightweight. While I agree the performance difference will be negligible mostly, OP didn't provide any scope. As such any further discussion of this is wasteful.

Comment: @RoAchterberg, actually thought I would try it and see what the difference is and seems that it's not how you think it is, this code (on the short text) is about 50% faster.

Comment: Well then I can only encourage OP to accept your answer, although it is not my place to do so at all. Care to share the data though? I like to form my own opinions ;).

Answer (score 2):

You can use `explode()` but it's relatively expensive, as you have to chop, remove, then glue together. Considering the simple criteria you have, `substr()` and `strpos()` are a better choice. Try this:

```
<?php

$input = 'First#Second#Third#...#...# and etc.';

// Locate second # and grab everything after that position.
$output = substr($input, strpos($input, '#', strpos($input, '#') + 1) + 1);

var_dump($output); // Third#...#...# and etc.
```